# Camel-Salesforce losing response on 500

Tags: apache-camel, salesforce

I have a apex call with some custom error messages coming back e.g. on 500

```
{"errors":[{"status":"unknown","message":"this is a message"}]
```

in the class `DefaultRestClient` it makes a call to 
`List<RestError> restErrors = this.readErrorsFrom(responseContent, this.format, this.objectMapper, this.xStream);`

which blows up as the rest message comes back is not a list. 
The returning line that gets called is

```
 return new SalesforceException("Unexpected error: " + reason + ", with content: " + responseContent, statusCode);
```

but since responseContent is a InputStream the SalesforceException gets generated as e.g. `Unexpected error: Server Error, with content: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7cfaab0a.`
so the content itself gets lost due to calling InputStream.toString() rather than a direct translation of the message.

Is there anyway to preserve this ?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried with a newer version

Comment: Hi Claus, version 2.21.0.fuse-730078, I can still see the issue (it might be just because we are using a custom error) on https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-salesforce/camel-salesforce-component/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/salesforce/internal/client/DefaultRestClient.java
I have overcome the error by creating a subclass of DefaultRestClient and overwriting createRestException ... unsure if this is the correct way.

Comment: Okay so its both good and bad to include the message in an exception that gets wired back via http 500 errors, as it can leak internal details. IMHO its better to not do this (sensitive data) and report detailed error on the server side only. So I would argue the response content should not be .toString in the exception at all

Comment: That may be true, but the issue is the same for a 400 error too. It still tries to parse it to a List<Error> but the object mapper is coupled to JsonUtils, so cannot control how to deserialise this message and it and fails for json { “errors”:[ ....]} although I found a work around. Being able to inject the ObjectMapper seems more of a cleaner solution.

Comment: Okay you are welcome to look at the source code, for example at the master branch and provide a PR with suggest code changes.